# Magento 2 ui component multi select selected option not working on edit action

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, uicomponent

[image]

this is add new form this is working.

```
<field name="available_time">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Testing\AB\Model\Config\Source\AvailableTime</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">required</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Available Time</item>
            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">available_time</item>
            <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
            
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

But edit this is not working . select radio not checked.

[image]

Comment: Please share you Dataprovider file.

Comment: edit area select option click not work.

Comment: public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $blog) {
            $this->loadedData[$blog->getId()] = $blog->getData();
        }
        return $this->loadedData;
    }

Comment: The invalid option value pass in the employee status field That's why it's not working.

Comment: Please check my updated answer and update me if still has an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **You have to update your data provider file for this. Available time must be passed as an array. Right now it's a string that's why you can not see selected options.**

**Sample Code**

```
public function getData() {
    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        return $this->loadedData;
    }

    $items = $this->collection->getItems();
    foreach ($items as $blog) {
        $blog->setData('emp_status', explode(',', $blog->getData('emp_status') ?? ''));
        $this->loadedData[$blog->getId()] = $blog->getData();
    }
    return $this->loadedData;
}
```

**You can replace emp_status with your column employee status column name**

Comment: public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $blog) {
            $this->loadedData[$blog->getId()] = $blog->getData();
        }
        return $this->loadedData;
    }